# How can I get permission to write to the gem directory in Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to build my first application in Ruby on Rails, but when I run `bundle install` I get this message:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

   /usr/bin/ruby2.1 -r ./siteconf20150921-23095-eac5m6.rb extconf.rb  checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes Building nokogiri using
packaged libraries. checking for gzdopen() in -lz... no zlib is
missing; necessary for building libxml2
*** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
options.

Provided configuration options:     --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
--without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby2.1
--help  --clean     --use-system-libraries  --enable-static
--disable-static    --with-zlib-dir     --without-zlib-dir
--with-zlib-include     --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
--with-zlib-lib     --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
--enable-cross-build    --disable-cross-build

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/tmp/bundler20150921-23095-1bpxdrp/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2
for inspection. Results logged to
/tmp/bundler20150921-23095-1bpxdrp/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.6.2), and Bundler
cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.2'`
succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried to install Nokogiri using:

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.6.2
```

but got this message:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
  You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.1.0 directory.
```

I also tried to run:

```
sudo gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.6.2
```

but got this message:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
installing nokogiri:    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 -r ./siteconf20150921-24140-1odizm6.rb extconf.rb checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes Building nokogiri using
packaged libraries. checking for gzdopen() in -lz... no zlib is
missing; necessary for building libxml2
*** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
options.

Provided configuration options:     --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
  --with-opt-include    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
  --with-opt-lib    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
  --without-make-prog   --srcdir=.  --curdir    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby2.1
  --help    --clean     --use-system-libraries  --enable-static
  --disable-static  --with-zlib-dir     --without-zlib-dir
  --with-zlib-include   --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
  --with-zlib-lib   --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
  --enable-cross-build  --disable-cross-build

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection. Results
logged to
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

I'm new to Ubuntu and Ruby on Rails. How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing prerequisites.

Nokogiri's "[Troubleshooting Ubuntu/Debian Installation](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#ubuntu___debian)" documentation says:

> Here’s what you should do if you should find yourself in this situation:
>
> ```
> 1 sudo apt-get install ruby-dev zlib1g-dev
> ```
>
> Please report it as a bug if this doesn’t work for you (see Getting Help for details).

Because you're using Ubuntu and doing a normal install, you'll need `sudo` to do any gem installs.

I'd strongly recommend using rbenv or RVM to manage your Ruby installation(s) as they'll make your life a lot easier. If you use those, you won't need to use `sudo` again, except for any system-wide prerequisite libraries.